# In Tensorflow, how can I change value of elements between two non-zero elements?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I have a tensor of 0 or 1 values like this:

```
A = [[1,0,1,0,1,1,0],
     [0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
     [0,0,0,1,0,0,1],
     [0,1,1,1,0,0,0]]
```

and I want to end with something like this:

```
A = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
     [0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
     [0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
     [0,1,1,1,0,0,0]]
```

So, basically, I'd like to fill with 1s all the values between the first and the last non-zero element for each row.
I tried this:

```
def call(input):
   indices = tf.where(input)
   input[indices[0][0]:indices[-1][0], indices[0][1]:indices[-1][1]] = 1
   return input
```

but of course it tells me I can't edit a tensor. Moreover I think the slicing is wrong. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs it, I was able to do so:

```
def foo(a):
   seq1 = tf.sequence_mask(tf.argmax(a,axis=1),maxlen=a.shape[1]) # get first zero values for each row 
   seq2 = tf.reverse(tf.sequence_mask(tf.argmax(tf.reverse(a,axis = [1]),axis=1),maxlen=a.shape[1]),axis = [1]) # get last zero values for each row
   return tf.cast(~(seq1|seq2),tf.float32) # OR operation and cast to float
```